# How can I set a breakpoint on _NSLockError()

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, multithreading, nslock

I am trying to debug multiple threads.

```
 *** -[NSLock lock]: deadlock (<NSLock: 0xc388ab0> '(null)')
 *** Break on _NSLockError() to debug.
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the Xcode debugger (which uses gdb under the hood), pause the app and in the console enter:

```
b _NSLockError
```

Then the debugger will stop the app when _NSLockError happens, which you should be able to check the backtrace.

Comment: +1 You can also open the breakpoints window (`cmd-opt-b`) and add it there.

Comment: Alternatively use the XCode 4 GUI to set the breakpoint.  Instructions are posted at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299785/break-on-nslockerror-to-debug-how-to)